Moving place minhaguim
Let's say a convert adopts minhag A in Erets Israel. Then he moves to Houtz Laaretz when there is only a minhag hamakom B which he must follow.
Then he moves back to Israel where minhag B is also present.
Should he keep minhag B or come back to minhag A?

Welcome to MiYodeya Haim and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

And does he need in this case Hatarat Nedarim?

Please [edit] your question if you wish to add new sub-questions - there is an Edit "button" below every question to do so
